# Javascript and Doctype in firefox bug

Tags: javascript, firefox, doctype

i have this javascript code :

```
function pageWidth() {
    return (window.innerWidth != null
        ? window.innerWidth
        : (document.body != null
            ? document.body.offsetWidth
            : null
    ));
}

function bodyloaded() {
    winWidth = pageWidth();
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    scrAmount = Math.floor(
        ((document.body['scrollWidth'] - document.body.offsetWidth)/2) + 8
    );
    scrollBy(scrAmount, 0);
}
```

and is applied on body tags in methods onload and onresize , the problem is if i put any doctype , this code doesnt work on firefox but works on IE.
I debug the value of scrollWidth and  offsetWidth , and allways get the same value , this happend using a Doctype.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

In quirks mode (no doctype or a quirks mode doctype), `document.body.scrollWidth` actually returns the scrollWidth of the document instead of the body in some cases.  In standards mode (with most doctypes), it returns the scrollWidth of the body, and `document.documentElement.scrollWidth` returns the scrollWidth of the document in some cases.  See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollwidth for the spec draft for this.